# Which exception should I throw if a module is not the correct version?

Tags: python, exception, version

This may have been asked before or I may be overly pedantic, but my own searches have come up empty.

Looking through the [Python 2.x exceptions page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html), I'm not sure which one I should `raise` if my script determines that the `__version__` of a module that's been imported, e.g. `cv2`, is not the correct version. For example, a script I'm working on requires OpenCV version 3; what's the best exception to `raise` in the following block if it determines that the version != 3?

```
import cv2
if not cv2.__version__.startswith('3'):
    raise ValueError('OpenCV _3_ required')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create you own custom exception if the existing ones don't suffice.

```
class VersionError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        Exception.__init__(self,msg)
```

Comment: Ah yes, I realize I can just add my own, I was just curious about those that are already available. But this works too!

Comment: This feels like overkill to me.  Also, You could simplify this by _not_ providing an `__init__`.  `class VersionError(Exception): pass` would work just fine (or, if you really want to go the extra mile, you could add a docstring isntead of `pass`)

Comment: Yeah that works too. But since OP had passed their own custom message, I felt I should add the `__init__` call with `msg` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a lot of options depending on what you want to do with this exception... Generally, I'd expect the install scripts to handle setting up the appropriate versions of dependencies so I might think of this as a simple runtime assertion -- Therefore `AssertionError` may be appropriate.

This one is really nice -- You don't need an `if` statement, just an `assert`:

```
assert cv2.__version__.startswith('3'), 'OpenCV _3_ required'
```

My next bet would be to use `RuntimeError` as that is really meant to be a general exception that happens at runtime (and isn't usually meant to be caught)...  It's a pretty general "Oh snap, something bad happened that we cannot recover from.  Lets just spit out an error to let the user know what happened".

Comment: Thanks! This is about what I was looking for